# MassTransit Azure ServiceBus force the connection to use HTTPS rather than AMQP

Tags: .net, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

How can we  force MassTransit to use HTTPS to connect to Azure Service Bus rather than AMQP?

Our application is behind an enterprise firewall. It need to send/receive messages from Azure Topic. We would prefer to use HTTPS over AMQP so it is easier for the security management purpose.

The app has following settings

- .NET Framework 4.6.2
- MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core 6..1.0
- Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 4.1.1

From Azure Service Bus documentation, we should be able to set the transport type to AmqpWebSockets which should use HTTPS for communication. The connection string look like this:

```
Endpoint=sb://test.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=secret;TransportType=AmqpWebSockets
```

(ref: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/14133)

If we use the `TopicClient` from `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 4.1.1`, we can see the traffic goes through port 443. The sample code is

```
class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serviceBus = new ServiceBus();
        await serviceBus.SendMessageAsync();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class ServiceBus
{
    public async Task SendMessageAsync()
    {
        const int numberOfMessages = 10;
        topicClient = new TopicClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, TopicName);
        // Send messages.
        await SendMessagesAsync(numberOfMessages);

        Console.ReadKey();

        await topicClient.CloseAsync();
    }

    public async Task SendMessagesAsync(int numberOfMessagesToSend)
    {
        try
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfMessagesToSend; i++)
            {
                // Create a new message to send to the topic.
                string messageBody = $"Message {i}";
                var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));

                // Write the body of the message to the console.
                Console.WriteLine($"Sending message: {messageBody}");

                // Send the message to the topic.
                await topicClient.SendAsync(message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} :: Exception: {exception.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

However, when we use the same connection string which has `TransportType=AmqpWebSockets`, MassTransit still uses AMQP port `5671`:

```
public class Order : IModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}


public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Host(ConnectionString);
    });
    await bus.StartAsync();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var order = new Order() { Id = i, Amount = 20, Description = "Test order" };
        await bus.Publish(order);
    }
}
```

Here is the traffic captured by Wireshark:
[image]

It is interesting that it uses port `443` for first few packets then changed to port `5671`

Comment: AmqpTransportSettings.UseSslStreamSecurity Property property must be set to true . by default it is true. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.amqp.amqptransportsettings.usesslstreamsecurity?view=azure-dotnet&viewFallbackFrom=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_Amqp_AmqpTransportSettings_UseSslStreamSecurity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution, you can set the transport type when setting up the bus:

```
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Host(ConnectionString, hc => hc.TransportType = TransportType.AmqpWebSockets);
    cfg.PrefetchCount = 1;
    AddSubscriptionEndpoints(context, cfg);
});
```

Bingo, it now uses port `443`
[image]