# Calling Publish() on MassTransit IPublishEndpoint with Azure Service Bus doesn't return

Tags: c#, .net-core, azureservicebus, masstransit

I experience issues publishing messages to Azure Service Bus using Mass Transit. Calling `await Publish()` on either `IBus` or `IPublishEndpoint` doesnt return. When i switching provider to `InMemory` it returns as expected.

To narrow down the issue, i used the MassTransit AzureServiceBus sample application https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-AzureServiceBus. Only setting the connection string in appsettings.json and leaving the default Startup configuration pointing to ASB

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((_, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureServiceBus"));

        cfg.Send<OrderShipped>(s => s.UseSessionIdFormatter(c => c.Message.OrderId.ToString("D")));
    });
});
```

When hitting the `Put()` endpoint in `ShipmentController` the `await _publishEndpoint.Publish()` call doesn't return. `return Ok()` is never reached.

```cs
namespace Sample.Api.Controllers
{
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Contracts;
    using MassTransit;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;


    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ShipmentController :
        ControllerBase
    {
        readonly ILogger<ShipmentController> _logger;
        readonly IPublishEndpoint _publishEndpoint;

        public ShipmentController(ILogger<ShipmentController> logger, IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _publishEndpoint = publishEndpoint;
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Put(Guid orderId)
        {
            await _publishEndpoint.Publish(new OrderShipped
            {
                OrderId = orderId,
                Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now
            });

            return Ok(new {OrderId = orderId});
        }
    }
}
```

When switching to InMemory the `await _publishEndpoint.Publish()` in `ShipmentController` returns as expected.

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

    x.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Send<OrderShipped>(s => s.UseSessionIdFormatter(c => c.Message.OrderId.ToString("D")));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the requests on port 5671 being refused in Wireshark. Switching `TransportType` to `AmqpWebSockets` (port 443) as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60333992/1573728 did the trick, so definitely Firewall issue.

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((_, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureServiceBus"), cfg => cfg.TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets);

        cfg.Send<OrderShipped>(s => s.UseSessionIdFormatter(c => c.Message.OrderId.ToString("D")));
    });
}
```

In my opinion MassTransit should have thrown an Exception at some point since it wasn't able to publish, or simply because of a timeout.

Comment: If you specify a CancellationToken on the call to Publish, you can cancel it [after a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562077/specify-publish-timeouts-in-mass-transit) or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking at the logs, but my guess is that your bus is unable to connect to Azure. Firewalls, etc. can be the root cause, it has nothing to do with MassTransit itself.

You should also be passing the `CancellationToken` from the controller to `Publish`, so that the call will be canceled if the controller signals cancellation.

Comment: The configuration of ASB is actually done when running the application - queue is setup, so it's able to connect to ASB. However i was not able to reproduce this issue when running the application on another computer. It could be machine/infrastructure configuration.

But how do i track the issue? There's exceptions thrown, nothing to see in the Event Viewer and the call simply doesn't return thus leaving the process hanging.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the exact same behavior and I fixed it by switching from a ServiceBus "Basic" tier to a "Standard" one.

I know it is mentioned in the documentation but it is easy to miss it and then think the problem is due to another reason.

I hope this helps to save you some time dear reader! ;-)